# Delphi/Firemonkey, TDummy accept events or not?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Does anyone know, TDummy accepts events like "MouseDown,MouseMove,MouseUp" on Delphi/Firemonkey ?

If, hopefully yes, how to do it?

I already set HitTest to True but also didn't work

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Objects3D.TDummy

Comment: Well, according to that documentation, `TDummy` has published `OnMouse...`  events, so what is the actual issue?

Comment: events don't work ...
or maybe I miss something

Comment: Those dont work because TDummy.DoRayCastIntersect is not implemented in FMX code. If you want something invisible with Mouse events you can use a TCube with zero opacity. Otherwise, you can copy the TCube.DoRayCastIntersect code into TDummy.DoRayCastIntersect.